# Keyboard without any EditText causes strange behavior like a D-pad. How to solve?

Tags: android

I had an activity that opens already with the keyboard opened because I use the attribute android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" at AndroidManifest.
But in this activity I don't have any Edit Text (only one button) and I need to read each character typed (once per time) by user.
So I had overridden the dispatchKeyEvent to read each character.
I read each character (only one character) and my application completes the rest of the word.

The problem is that since the keyboard is being showed and there is no one Edit Text, when click in any character Android OS kind selects the button (or any other view) on screen. This selection is kind I was using a D-pad.
And if the back button is pressed it will "select" any other view from back activity.

I think that since there is no Edit Text to works with keyboard the activity does not know how to handle the characters typed.

I had attached at Tiny server a simple project with two activities that can be used as sample to reproduce the issue: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=70317553185010262971

Also had attached a screenshot at TinyPic:

- http://tinypic.com/r/2uhmwdy/8

Below also are all my codes:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testbug"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testbug.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.testbug.TestActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java (1º activity)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**TestActivity.java (2º activity)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvType;
Button testButton;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count);

    tvType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
    testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    count++;
    if(count==6){
        hideKeyboard();
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

private void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
}
```

**Layouts:**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_count.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TestButton"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:text="Press any key 3 times to Hide keyboard\n Then Press Back button. The same behavior of selection of button will happens on back activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Have you tried adding an EditText and make it hidden.

Comment: Yes. Does not work. :( Occurs the same problem.

Comment: And you added <requestfocu/> in the EditText?

Comment: Yes, I tried it too and didn't work. Seems that need something on screen to receive the typed, if you type in the way I need it selects some view. If you download the code you can check this behavior too. Thanks for help.